# SQL Server return NULL (or value) in case entry does not exist - Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a populated table with a 'Number' as `PK`. I would like a query which searches for a specific number, and if it is not found then it would return "NULL" not a no value.

I have managed to do it for one return:

```
SELECT (SELECT Risk_Impact FROM [dbo].[RFC] WHERE Number = 'RFC-018345')
```

However I would like to select multiple columns like:

```
SELECT (SELECT Risk_Impact, Risk_Impact, BI_TestingOutcome FROM [dbo].[RFC] WHERE Number = 'RFC-018345')
```

However it is giving me an error:

> "Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."

Can you please assist?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try only `SELECT Risk_Impact, Risk_Impact, BI_TestingOutcome FROM [dbo].[RFC] WHERE Number = 'RFC-018345'`

Comment: Yes that works however I want it returning: NULL | NULL | NULL when the value RFC-xxxxx is not present

Comment: Why are you trying to SELECTR Risk_Impact twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
select p.* from (select 1 as t ) v
left join  (select * from [dbo].[RFC] WHERE Number = 'RFC-018345') p
on 1=1
```

Comment: You could CROSS JOIN and eliminate subquery:)

Comment: @HansLindgren - for `cross join` to work, you need data to be returned from `RFC`

Answer (score -1):

In sql server should be use isnull function like this

```
SELECT isnull((SELECT Risk_Impact FROM [dbo].[RFC] WHERE Number = 'RFC-018345'),0)
```

Comment: Does not solve the problem I am having I want SQL returning

NULL | NULL | NULL

if the value number is not present

Comment: Yes for Risk_Impact only it works however I want to output for multiple columns as well :)

Answer (score -1):

Refined @Sagar query:

And better indentation would probably be more helpful for people to learn from.

<strike>Ex:
    SELECT 
        [dbo].[RFC].* 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 1 AS Col1) AS V
        CROSS JOIN 
        [dbo].[RFC] 
    WHERE Number = 'RFC-018345'</strike>

Edit: I got caught up in removing the subquery. Working query:

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[RFC].* 
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS Col1) AS V
    LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[RFC] 
    ON Number = 'RFC-018345'
```

(I would also advocate to not SELECT *, anywhere near production, but to always be explicit about the columns in the result set. Ex:

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[RFC].[Risk_Impact], 
    [dbo].[RFC].[BI_TestingOutcome]
FROM 
    (SELECT 1 AS Col1) AS V
    LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[RFC] 
    ON Number = 'RFC-018345'
```

)

Comment: for `cross join` to work, you need data to be returned from `RFC`. Check this. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 as col1) t CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 a)v WHERE t.a = 0`

Comment: This will not work..if Number does not exists in RFC table

Comment: @HansLindgren - You can either correct your answer or delete it. in its current state, it's not constructive to the question